# How to get the uploaded image url in media_handle_upload()?

Tags: uploads

I am referring to this codex, https://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/media_handle_upload

There I can attach the uploaded image to the post as attachments by this :

`$attachment_id = media_handle_upload( 'my_image_upload', $_POST['post_id'] );`

But, I want to just get the `url` of the uploaded image, without adding the image as the post attachments.

How can I get that uploaded image url ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can get it with:

```
wp_get_attachment_url();
```

More info in the [codex](https://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/wp_get_attachment_url)

In your example:

```
$attachment_id = media_handle_upload( 'my_image_upload', $_POST['post_id'] );
$attachment_url = wp_get_attachment_url($attachment_id);
echo $attachment_url;
```

Comment: Hi, I don't want to add it as attachments to the post.

Comment: I edited my answer. Hope this helps.